# Why I am getting warning information like: Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute?

Tags: java, jpa

Hello all,

Have a nice day. In my maven project, I am using JPA for back-end communication and eclipse-link. But when I am trying to perform lazy loading on my Model component I am getting the above warning information. I have already added the plugins to pom.xml and also in persistent.xml, the  is added, still I am unable to solve my problem. Please anyone help me. Below is my entity class.

Gdu.java

```
package com.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


@Entity
@Table(name = "GDU")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Gdu.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdu g"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Gdu.findByGduId", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdu g WHERE g.gduId = :gduId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Gdu.findByName", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdu g WHERE g.name = :name"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Gdu.findByHttpPort", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdu g WHERE g.httpPort = :httpPort"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Gdu.findByModbusPort", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdu g WHERE g.modbusPort = :modbusPort")})
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ5", sequenceName="gduSeq", allocationSize=1)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@gduId")




 public class Gdu implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        // @Max(value=?) @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ5")
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "GDU_ID")
        private BigDecimal gduId;
        @Size(max = 10)
        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "HTTP_PORT")
        private BigInteger httpPort;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "MODBUS_PORT")
        private BigInteger modbusPort;
        @JoinColumn(name = "PLANT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PLANT_ID")
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Plant plantId;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gduId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Collection<Inverter> inverterCollection;
        @JoinColumn(name = "GDUTYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "GDUTYPE_ID")
        @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Gdutype gdutypeId;

        public Gdu() {
        }

        public Gdu(BigDecimal gduId) {
        this.gduId = gduId;
        }

        public Gdu(BigDecimal gduId, BigInteger httpPort, BigInteger modbusPort) {
        this.gduId = gduId;
        this.httpPort = httpPort;
        this.modbusPort = modbusPort;
        }

        //override equals and hashcode and setters and getters are here
        }
```

Here for plantId and gdutypeId I am getting the warning.

```
The warning is :  [EL Info]: 2014-09-05 14:39:14.144--ServerSession(1385008216)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2014-09-05 14:39:14.264--ServerSession(1385008216)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [gdutypeId] for the entity class [class com.model.Gdu] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
[EL Warning]: metadata: 2014-09-05 14:39:14.264--ServerSession(1385008216)--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [plantId] for the entity class [class com.model.Gdu] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
Here is Inverter and Plant and GduType. Please have a look

package com.model;
//imports are here
@Entity
@Table(name = "GDUTYPE")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Gdutype.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdutype g"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Gdutype.findByGdutypeId", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdutype g WHERE g.gdutypeId = :gdutypeId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Gdutype.findByProductName", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdutype g WHERE g.productName = :productName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Gdutype.findByApiName", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdutype g WHERE g.apiName = :apiName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Gdutype.findByApiVersion", query = "SELECT g FROM Gdutype g WHERE g.apiVersion = :apiVersion")})
public class Gdutype implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "GDUTYPE_ID")
    private BigDecimal gdutypeId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME")
    private String productName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "API_NAME")
    private String apiName;
    @Size(max = 5)
    @Column(name = "API_VERSION")
    private String apiVersion;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "gdutypeId",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Gdu> gduCollection;

    public Gdutype() {
    }

    public Gdutype(BigDecimal gdutypeId) {
        this.gdutypeId = gdutypeId;
    }
    public Gdutype(BigDecimal gdutypeId, String productName, String apiName) {
        this.gdutypeId = gdutypeId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.apiName = apiName;
    }
    //setters and getters ,hashcode,equals
}


package com.model;
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVERTER")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Inverter.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Inverter i"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Inverter.findByInverterId", query = "SELECT i FROM Inverter i WHERE i.inverterId = :inverterId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Inverter.findByName", query = "SELECT i FROM Inverter i WHERE i.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Plant.findByNominalPower", query = "SELECT p FROM Plant p WHERE p.nominalPower = :nominalPower")})
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ4", sequenceName="inverterSeq", allocationSize=1)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@inverterId")
public class Inverter implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ4")    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "INVERTER_ID")
    private BigDecimal inverterId;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NOMINAL_POWER")
    private double nominalPower;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "inverterId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Mppt> mpptCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLANT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PLANT_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Plant plantId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "PCI_ID", referencedColumnName = "PCI_ID")
    @ManyToOne(" fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Pci pciId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "INVERTERTYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "IT_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Invertertype invertertypeId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "GDU_ID", referencedColumnName = "GDU_ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Gdu gduId;
    public Inverter() {  }
}


package com.model;
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLANT")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Plant.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Plant p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Plant.findByPlantId", query = "SELECT p FROM Plant p WHERE p.plantId = :plantId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Plant.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Plant p WHERE p.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Plant.findByOperator", query = "SELECT p FROM Plant p WHERE p.operator = :operator"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Plant.findByCommissioning", query = "SELECT p FROM Plant p WHERE p.commissioning = :commissioning"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Plant.findByNominalPower", query = "SELECT p FROM Plant p WHERE p.nominalPower = :nominalPower"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Plant.findByContador", query = "SELECT p FROM Plant p WHERE p.contador = :contador")})
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ2", sequenceName="plantSeq", allocationSize=1)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@plantId")
public class Plant implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ2")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "PLANT_ID")
    private BigDecimal plantId;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "OPERATOR")
    private String operator;
    @Column(name = "COMMISSIONING")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date commissioning;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NOMINAL_POWER")
    private double nominalPower;
    @Column(name = "CONTADOR")
    private BigInteger contador;
    @Column(name = "LONGITUDE")
    private BigDecimal longitude;
    @Column(name = "LATITUDE")
    private BigDecimal latitude;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "plantId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Sensor> sensorCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "plant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Userplant> userplantCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "REPORT_ID", referencedColumnName = "REPORT_ID")
    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Report reportId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "INSTALLATION_ID", referencedColumnName = "INSTALLATION_ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Installation installationId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "plantId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Gdu> gduCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "plantId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Inverter> inverterCollection;

    public Plant() {
    }

    public Plant(BigDecimal plantId) {
        this.plantId = plantId;
    }

    public Plant(BigDecimal plantId, double nominalPower) {
        this.plantId = plantId;
        this.nominalPower = nominalPower;
    }
}
```

Comment: PLease show the implementation of 'Inverter' and `Gdutype`

Comment: Hello Jens, I have added my Plant,Inverter and Gdutype. please have a look and let me know a solution from you...

Comment: Think your annotations are not correct. Look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) how the mapping mast look like.

Comment: Hello Jems, can you please tell me where  the mistake is done? if you are telling about @ManyToOne(" fetch = FetchType.LAZY), sorry this is like  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) in Inverter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using OneToMany and ManyToOne mappings with lazy loading on `Plant` and `GduType`. This requires byte-code changes to your POJO (Weaving).

EclipseLink uses weaving to enhance both JPA entities and Plain Old Java Object (POJO) classes for such things as lazy loading, change tracking, fetch groups, and internal optimizations.

EclipseLink uses weaving to enable the following for POJO classes:

1. lazy loading (indirection)
2. change tracking
3. fetch groups
4. internal optimizations.

To resolve this warning you have 2 options:

1. Remove lazy loading.
2. Configure [Dynamic weaving](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Application_Development_%28ELUG%29#Configuring_Dynamic_Weaving_Using_the_EclipseLink_Agent).

Reference : [EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Application_Development_%28ELUG%29#Using_Weaving.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I think I need to create session.xml file for my application. Am I right?,please tell me.

Comment: Hello Barun, if I will remove implements Serializable , I think everything will be fine. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: @Rasmitapatra Your welcome. Dont forget to mark this as the answer.